# XMLHttpRequest not sending JSON just an empty string

Tags: javascript, ajax

xhttp.send(data) is sending an empty string instead of the data I look at other examples and this should work. I am looking over this over and over and can't figure out what is wrong. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

````
    <head>

        <title>Tuition Reimbursement Management System </title>

    </head>
    <body>

      <h4>User Name</h4>
      <input type="text"id="user">
      <h4>Password</h4><br>
      <input type="password"id="pass">
      <button onclick="login()">Login</button>



    </body>


<script>


function login(){

let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

let user = document.getElementById("user").value;
let pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
     console.log(xhttp.responseText);
 }
}

xhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/one/login.do",true);

xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

let employee = {user:user,pass:pass};
data = JSON.stringify(employee);
console.log(employee);// Object { user: "bob", pass: "password" }

console.log(data); //{"user":"bob","pass":"password"}
console.log(xhttp); // empty string
xhttp.send(data)

}

</script>

</html> ```
````